# sklearn MinMaxScaler() with groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have two features `rank` and `ratings` for different product IDs under different categories scraped from an ecommerce website on different dates.

sample dataframe available here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import warnings; warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler

df=pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amanaroratc/hello-world/master/testdf.csv')
df.head()

      category                bid         date  rank    ratings
0   Aftershave  ASCDBNYZ4JMSH42B    2021-10-01  61.0    462.0
1   Aftershave  ASCDBNYZ4JMSH42B    2021-10-02  69.0    462.0
2   Aftershave  ASCDBNYZ4JMSH42B    2021-10-05  89.0    463.0
3   Aftershave  ASCE3DZK2TD7G4DN    2021-10-01  309.0   3.0
4   Aftershave  ASCE3DZK2TD7G4DN    2021-10-02  319.0   3.0
```

I want to normalize `rank` and `ratings` using `MinMaxScaler()` from sklearn.

I tried

```
cols=['rank','ratings']
features=df[cols]
scaler1=MinMaxScaler()
df_norm[['rank_norm_mm', 'ratings_norm_mm']] = scaler1.fit_transform(features)
```

This normalizes over entire dataset.
I want to do this over each category for each particular date using `groupby`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
file = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amanaroratc/hello-world/master/testdf.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(file)

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

cols=['rank','ratings']

def f(x):
    scaler1=MinMaxScaler()
    x[['rank_norm_mm', 'ratings_norm_mm']] = scaler1.fit_transform(x[cols])
    return x

df = df.groupby(['category', 'date']).apply(f)
```

Another solution:

```
file = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amanaroratc/hello-world/master/testdf.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(file)

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler1=MinMaxScaler()
cols=['rank','ratings']

df= df.join(df.groupby(['category', 'date'])[cols]
               .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(scaler1.fit_transform(x), index=x.index))
               .add_prefix('_norm_mm'))
```

Comment: I want to normalize on different dates as well. I just do df=df.groupby(['category','date']).apply(f) or something else?

Comment: @AmanArora - You are right, edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby_apply`:

```
>>> df.groupby(['category', 'date'])[['rank', 'ratings']] \
      .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(scaler1.fit_transform(x), columns=x.columns)) \
      .droplevel(2).reset_index()

     category        date  rank  ratings
0  Aftershave  2021-10-01   0.0      1.0
1  Aftershave  2021-10-01   1.0      0.0
2  Aftershave  2021-10-02   0.0      1.0
3  Aftershave  2021-10-02   1.0      0.0
4  Aftershave  2021-10-05   0.0      0.0
```